# I couldn't understand what the second printf printed

Tags: c, printf, memory-address

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=10;
    printf("value of x is %d\n",x);
    printf("address of x is %d\n",&x);
    printf("address of x is %p\n",&x);

}
```

ouptup :

```
value of x is 10
address of x is 2686748
address of x is 0028FF1C
```

Comment: The second `printf` is Undefined Behavior.  It could do anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have to read the manual

Comment: Why could you not understand it?   2686748 decimal is 0028FF1C hex.  It's correct that the second printf() is UB, but I would like to understand why you asked this qustions at all, since the second printf() output the same value as the third printf() for the same '&x' argument....

Comment: yes,sir. now i got it.

Answer (score 1):

The second and third `printf` produce undefined behavior.

According to C99 specification,

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

In this case the undefined behavior can be explained: the printout produces a decimal representation of the hex address `0028FF1C`, which is `2686748`.

You can fix the third `printf` by adding a conversion to `void*`:

```
printf("address of x is %p\n", (void*)&x);
```

Comment: Actually both, the second and 3rd `printf` invoke UB.

Comment: @Olaf You are right, he's passing `int*` to `%p`, which takes `void*`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("address of x is %d\n",&x);
```

This is undefined behavior, because you are not supposed to print an address (`&x`) with the `%d` specifier. Instead, your third line is what you must use, except you also need to cast to `void *`, because `%p` expects a `void *`, not an `int *`.

The second printf, by the way, and all `printf` calls, return the number of characters printed, so your use of the word "return" in your question title is misleading.

Check out the documentation
[`printf`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?printf(3))

Answer (score 0):

2686748 is the decimal of 0028FF1C

Comment: thanks for your response

Comment: You are welcome sir! Regardless of criticism, don't give up. All doubt is important. Did you find your answer?

Comment: yes sir i got it

Answer (score 0):

**second printf** you should use ***unsigned integer***(memory cannt be -ve number),, so use %u (if i remember correclty.)
third **printf** is correct.

Comment: The third line also invokes UB.